# Error building Android APK with React Native FBSDK due to wrong class path

Tags: java, android, react-native

I am getting this error when I try and do a signed APK.

I can only assume it's this problem but I can't seem to find a solution.

`Task ':react-native-fbsdk:verifyReleaseResources' class path has changed from 80125a25037a2373acdb7ca1870ee5ef to d977e14451869fdc62403ddedc7f963d`

```
> Task :react-native-fbsdk:verifyReleaseResources FAILED
Putting task artifact state for task ':react-native-fbsdk:verifyReleaseResources' into context took 0.0 secs.
Up-to-date check for task ':react-native-fbsdk:verifyReleaseResources' took 0.001 secs. It is not up-to-date because:
Task ':react-native-fbsdk:verifyReleaseResources' class path has changed from 80125a25037a2373acdb7ca1870ee5ef to d977e14451869fdc62403ddedc7f963d.
All input files are considered out-of-date for incremental task ':react-native-fbsdk:verifyReleaseResources'.
Unable do incremental execution: full task run
QueuedCruncher is using /Users/karl/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/27.0.1/aapt

Shutdown finished in 0ms

:react-native-fbsdk:verifyReleaseResources (Thread[Task worker for ':' Thread 6,5,main]) completed. Took 0.309 secs.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-fbsdk:verifyReleaseResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt
```

I can build the device on my phone absolutely fine. Just can't build an APK.

I've tried unlinking and uninstalling then installing and relinking `react-native-fbsdk` with no luck.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you found the solution? I have the same issue.

Comment: @Flavien, There was nothing specific I remember doing to fix this. I've had a lot of errors building Android lately, however, this Stack Overflow question might be of use to you, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47757074/react-native-fbsdk-error-no-resource-found-that-matches-the-given-name-attr-a/47786292#47786292